# How to use AWS EventBridge Role Event Transformer

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, sms, aws-event-bridge

With the source event published on EventBridge as:

```
{
  version: '0',
  id: '1234-5678-9102-3456-7890',
  'detail-type': 'My-Detail-Type',
  source: 'My-Source',
  account: '328927794502',
  time: '2021-01-29T23:52:48Z',
  region: 'us-east-1',
  resources: [],
  detail: { year: '2020' }
}
```

I go ahead and create the EventBridge Rule with the Target Transformer:

For the `Input Path` I enter:

```
{"data_joined":"$.detail.year"}
```

And for the Input Template I enter:

```
{"Data-Joined" : <data_joined>}
```

[image]

Now when this event is transformed and sent to the destination (it could be Lambda function, CloudWatch Event log group and etc) I expect the transformed event to be:

```
{
  version: '0',
  id: '1234-5678-9102-3456-7890',
  'detail-type': 'My-Detail-Type',
  source: 'My-Source',
  account: '328927794502',
  time: '2021-01-29T23:52:48Z',
  region: 'us-east-1',
  resources: [],
  detail: { Data-Joined: '2020' }
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work as I am not able to find this transformed event anywhere. Is there anything I should be doing differently

Comment: What event are you actual getting in the destination?

Comment: I am not getting any event in the destination (the destination is AWS CloudWatch Log Group. Once I remove the "Input Transformer" from the Rule, the event is properly reaches the  CloudWatch Log.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a Note on the [API_PutTargets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/APIReference/API_PutTargets.html) page with regard to CloudWatch:

> Note If your are using InputTransformer with CloudWatch Logs as a
> target, the Template must be
> {"timestamp":,"message":}.

In addition, I would assume that you already did it, but there is a [Common Issues with Transforming Input](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/transform-input.html)